# Socket.io connection url?

Tags: socket.io

I have the current setup:

1. Nodejs Proxy (running http-reverse-proxy) running on port 80.
2. Rails server running on port 3000
3. Nodejs web server running on port 8888

So any request starting with /nodejs/ will be redirected to nodejs web server on 8888.

Anything else will be redirected to the rails server on port 3000.

Currently Socket.io requires a connection url for io.connect.

*Note that **/nodejs/socket.io/socket.io.js** is valid and returns the required socket.io client js library.*

---

However, I am not able to specify connection_url to /nodejs/ on my server.

I have tried http://myapp.com/nodejs and other variants but I am still getting a 404 error with the following url http://myapp/socket.io/1/?t=1331851089106

### Is it possible to tell io.connect to prefix each connection url with /nodejs/ ?

Comment: Here is a similar question using sails: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36348956/sails-socket-io-connecting-to-a-different-url-than-the-one-passed-in?noredirect=1#comment60342478_36348956

Answer (score 65, accepted):

As of Socket.io version 1, resource has been replaced by path. Use :

```
var socket = io('http://localhost', {path: '/nodejs/socket.io'});
```

See: http://blog.seafuj.com/migrating-to-socketio-1-0

Answer (score 13):

you can specify resource like this:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost', {resource: 'nodejs'});
```

by default `resource = "socket.io"`

Comment: Actually I think it is needed to put `{resource: 'nodejs/socket.io'}` instead.

Comment: This is outdated as of v1.0. Resource has been replaced by path. Instead use: var socket = io('http://localhost', {
            'path': '/nodejs/socket.io'});

Answer (score 13):

If you are using express with nodejs:

Server side:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server, {path: '/octagon/socket.io'});
```

then

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        console.log('a user connected, id ' + socket.id);
        socket.on('disconnect', function() {
            console.log('a user disconnected, id '  + socket.id);
        })
})
socket.on('publish message ' + clientId, function(msg) {
        console.log('got message')
    })
```

Client side:

```
var socket = io('https://dev.octagon.com:8443', {path: '/octagon/socket.io'})
```

then

```
socket.emit('publish message ' + clientId, msg)
```

Comment: I found that in addition to the server side, on the client side, using `var socket = io({path: '/octagon/socket.io'})` works for me.

Answer (score 3):

I use below approach to achieve this goal:

client side:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8183/?clientId='+clientId,{"force new connection":true});
```

server side:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("url"+socket.handshake.url);
    clientId=socket.handshake.query.clientId;
    console.log("connected clientId:"+clientId);

});
```

reference:https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing#global-authorization

Comment: in this uri ; http://localhost:8183 ; why you use 8183 ? we know the port for socket io is 3000?

Comment: @shihab_returns You can assign any port that you want. You do not need to use 3000.

Answer (score 1):

If you are serving your app with express, then maybe you can check this out. Remember express uses http to serve your application.

```
const express   = require('express'),
      http      = require('http'),
      socketIo  = require('socket.io'),
      app       = express()

var server = http.createServer(app);
var io     = socketIo(server);

io.on('connection', (socket)=>{
      // run your code here
})

server.listen(process.env.PORT, ()=> {
    console.log('chat-app inintated succesfully')
})
```