# Sails socket io connecting to a different url than the one passed in

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, sails.js, sails.io.js

In production when I try to connect to my socket client in sails at 'https://something.com/api/' from the client url 'https://something.com/' I get a 404

```
https://something.com/socket.io/?__sails_io_sdk_version=0.13…owser&__sails_io_sdk_language=javascript&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LFGJG5g 404 (Not Found)
```

When I establish a socket connection in sails on my local machine it works.

## My Local Configuration.

CLIENT HOST

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

API HOST

```
http://localhost:1337/
```

HTML

```
<script src="sails.io.js" autoConnect="false"></script>
```

JS

```
connect() {
    this.socket = io.sails.connect('http://localhost:1337');// Works Fine
}
```

## My Production Configuration

CLIENT HOST

```
https://something.com/
```

API HOST

```
https://something.com/api/
```

JS

```
connect() {
    this.socket = io.sails.connect('https://something.com/api/');// Does not work
}
```

I made sure that autoConnect was defiantly set to false and that the only connection was happening via the connect() function. It seems that no matter what string I pass into the connect() function ( only in production ), it assumes the client url (https://something.com/) and drops the suffix /api/ from the production url (https://something.com/api/).

Comment: Do you realize that `https://something.com/api/` and `https://something.com` are the exact same host?   `/api` is part of the path, not the host definition.  So, in either case, you're trying to connect to the host `https://something.com`.  If you thought you were connecting to two separate server processes here, that's not the case in your production environment.

Comment: My terminology was lacking here. /api/ is mapped through nginx to a node server. My api is served through the /api/ path, how would you recommend I connect to the socket on that path if it has the same host but different paths. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You will have to figure out how to use a custom path with socket.io because the default socket.io connect code is likely getting rid of the `/api` prefix and just trying to connect to the host alone with it's own path.  A custom path prefix for socket.io is probably possible, but I don't know how off the top of my head.

Comment: You could pass a `path` option to `io.connect()` option hash. I only find it mentioned [in migration guide](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/#configuration-differences). Should be a starting point.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<script src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  io.sails.url = 'https://myapp.com'; // or where you want
</script>
```

The docs can be found here: http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/web-sockets/socket-client#?programmatic-configuration-using-iosails