# Connecting Sails Socket IO to Sails server running in consul

Tags: docker, sails.js, consul, sails.io.js

There's this μService architecture running as the backend, with a consul instance managing all the services. There's a particular server, A made with Sails, and with some relevant socket logic I'd like to use from another service B using sails.io.

Each service is running in its own Docker container, but they all connect to the same network.

So, when developing, I run the A container locally and simulate service B with a node script, with the logic showed [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js#for-nodejs). The service URL is quite simple given that I'm just running the container with an open port, so the URL sails.io uses to connect is `localhost:PORT`. Everything here well.

The problem comes when service A is run in the μService architecture. Each service runs in its own URL, for example `backend.com/api/SERVICE_NAME`, acting like a namespace, with every route under the namespace actually hitting the `SERVICE_NAME` service. So now sails.io has issues connecting to service A, **I presume**, because of the change in route.

Thes are all the variations I've tried given `const io = sailsIOClient(socketIOClient);`

```
io.sails.url = 'http://backend.com/api/SERVICE_NAME';
```

then

```
io.sails.url = 'http://backend.com';
io.sails.path = '/api/SERVICE_NAME'
```

then

```
io.sails.url = 'http://backend.com';
io.sails.path = '/api/SERVICE_NAME/socket.io/'
```

Then I stumbled with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36348956/sails-socket-io-connecting-to-a-different-url-than-the-one-passed-in#comment60868710_36348956) that refers to a `path` argument on the connect function of socket.io ([here's the specific](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/#configuration-differences)). I tried with that, setting `io.sails.autoConnect` to false and calling `io.sails.connect()` but I'm not being able to connect to the Sails app.

```
        Socket is trying to reconnect to Sails...
_-|>_-  (attempt #293)
```

I'm fairly certain the issue is that the client io can't reach the correct route to find the Sails app because of the architecture is set up.

Has someone dealt with a similar scenario? Suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us your dockerfiles ;) Seems like service B is not able to discover service A.

Comment: Service discovery doesn't seem to be an option, because all regular http routes work just fine. It's only the websocket connection the one that can't find the Sails app. I forgot to add, we're using *Haproxy* as a router and to balance traffic, can that be an issue with websockets?

Comment: I meant "issue" not "option" in the first line.